# PHP: Check if a value of an array is a key of another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this arrays:

$required_fields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => email
)
```

$posted_fields:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Roberto
    [email] => 
    [richiesta] => richiesta
)
```

I need to check if a value of $required_fields is in $posted_fields (and if it's null/empty).

Pseudocode:

```
foreach ($required_fields as $value_r)
{
   foreach ($posted_fields as $key_p=>$value_p)
   {
       if (in_array($value_r,$posted_fields)
       {      
          if ($value_p=='' || $value_p == NULL)
          {
              // others stuff
          }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: And the question is..?

Comment: Have you tried translating it into real code to see what happens?

Comment: I would reverse it. Loop over the values and use `array_key_exists` to check if the key exists in the other array. You will only need a single loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you something simplier, like

```
foreach ($required_fields as $required_value)
{
    if(!isset($posted_fields[$required_value]) || trim($posted_fields[$required_value]) == "")
    {
        //Mandatory field not set or empty
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code that you had provided I would change `if (in_array($value_r,$posted_fields)` line

```
foreach ($required_fields as $value_r)
{
   foreach ($posted_fields as $key_p => $value_p)
   {
       if ($value_r == $key_p)
       {      
          if ($value_p=='' || $value_p == NULL)
          {
              // others stuff
          }
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_key_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

```
foreach ($required_fields as $value_r) {
    if(array_key_exists($value_r, $posted_fields)) {
         // value exists in key
    }
}
```